# Can't transmit standard serializable object across WCF

Tags: wcf

I have created a very simple server and client console app demonstrating the issue I have in that I am trying to bring an instance of a serializable object across to the client but it fails on the server.

What am I missing??  I am NOT concerned right now having it Service orientated using DataContracts - I am simply trying to understand why the code as it stands doesn't bring the EJob accross to the client (it DOES however calls the 'Hello from the server' message)

Many thanks.

EDIT

Even if I decorate the EJob class with a DataContract attribute (like below) it STILL doesn't work - the object I receive on the client has LastName set to null?????

```
[DataContract]
public class EJob
{
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName = "Smith";
}
```

**SERVER**

```
namespace testServer
{
    [ServiceContract()]
    public interface IRemoteClient
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void SayHi(string msg);

        [OperationContract]
        void ProcessJob(EJob job);
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class EJob
    {
        public string LastName = "Smith";
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MngrServer.SendJob();
        }
    }

    public class MngrServer
    {
        public static void SendJob()
        {
            try
            {
                // send this off to the correct exe
                NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, true);

                string address = string.Format("net.tcp://localhost:33888/BatchMananger/client");
                EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress(address);

                // create the proxy pointing to the correct exe
                IRemoteClient clientProxy = ChannelFactory<IRemoteClient>.CreateChannel(binding, epa);

                clientProxy.SayHi("Hello from server");  <-- THIS WORKS FINE

                EJob job = new EJob { LastName = "Janssen" };

                clientProxy.ProcessJob(job);             <-- THIS RAISES AN EXCEPTION see below...
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = ex.Message;

                //The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while 
                //trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:job. The InnerException message was ''EndElement' 'job' 
                //from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' is not expected. Expecting element 'LastName'.'.  
            }

        }
    }

}
```

**CLIENT**

```
namespace testClient
{
    [ServiceContract()]
    public interface IRemoteClient
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void SayHi(string msg);

        [OperationContract]
        void ProcessJob(EJob job);
    }

    [Serializable()]
    public class EJob 
    {
        public string LastName = "Smith";
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MngrClient.Prepare();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// STATIC / INSTANCE 
    /// </summary>
    public class MngrClient : IRemoteClient
    {
        public void SayHi(string msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }

        public void ProcessJob(EJob job)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(job.LastName);
        }

        public static void Prepare()
        {
            // allow this class to be used! - so instances are created and info directly passed on to its static members.
            ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MngrClient));

            // create the net binding
            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, true);

            // define the tcpaddress
            string address = string.Format("net.tcp://localhost:33888/BatchMananger/client");

            // add a service point so my server can reach me
            sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRemoteClient), binding, address);

            // now open the service for business
            sh.Open();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `public string LastName = "Smith";` is a field, not a property.  Try `public string LastName { get; set; };` and see if that works.

Comment: Sorry - not sure I follow you here - please bear in mind that my call (SayHi) IS getting executed on the client. The IRemoteClient is implemented on the client exe.  On the server I simply create a channel/proxy to it!

Comment: I think you have server and client totally mixed up. The **server** is the part that **implements** the service contract and provides the functionality. The **client** is the one creating the `ClientProxy` - you seems to be calling it just backwards....

Comment: Just curious, why was this question downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your EJob datacontract is in a different namespace on the server vs. the client.  You need to either declare both classes in the same namespace, or use attributes to set the namespace on the client to match the namespace on the server

(Either the Datacontract attribute has a namespace value that you can pass, or there is a separate namespace attribute that you can use to tell WCF to use an alternate namespace for the contract, can't remember off the top of my head)

**EDIT**
Just verified -- it's the Namespace property of the DataContractAttribute that you want, so in your client-side declaration:

```
[DataContract(Namespace="EJobNamespaceAsItIsDeclaredOnTheServer")]
public class EJob ...
```

Now, it is very common to put all of your DataContracts in a separate assembly (called a contract assembly) that is referenced by both the client and the server.  You would want just the contract class definitions in that assembly, nothing else.

Comment: Two hours of cursing and it was the NAMESPACE!! As soon as I lifted the ServiceContract and EJob out in a common namespace it all works!  Thanks very much

Comment: I've been bitten by that one myself!

Answer (score 0):

You somehow have it all a bit backwards...

- given your service contract of `IRemoteClient`, you should then have an **implementation class** on the server-side that implements that interface:

  ```
  public class ServiceImplementation : IRemoteClient
  {
     public void SayHi(string msg)
     { 
         .....
     }

     public void ProcessJob(EJob job)
     {
         .....
     }
  }
  ```

  Also: the service methods should be **returning** something to the caller! Without a return type, you're kinda creating a *black-hole* of a service - you can call its methods, but nothing gets returned.... Plus: the service implementation class should ***NOT*** be hosting itself! Make that a separate class
- you should then have a **host class** on the server side that hosts this service:

  ```
  public class HostForYourService
  {
      public HostForYourService()
      {
          // send this off to the correct exe
          NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, true);

          string address = string.Format("net.tcp://localhost:33888/BatchMananger/client");
          EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress(address);

          ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceImplementation));

          // define the tcpaddress
          sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRemoteClient), binding, address);

          // now open the service for business
          sh.Open();
      }
  ```
- and then your client should build the client-side proxy for this service and call it

  ```
  public class YourServiceClient
  {
     public void CallService() 
     {
          NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, true);

          string address = string.Format("net.tcp://servername:33888/BatchMananger/client");
          EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress(address);

          // create the proxy pointing to the correct exe
          IRemoteClient clientProxy = ChannelFactory<IRemoteClient>.CreateChannel(binding, epa);

          clientProxy.SayHi("Hello from server");  <-- THIS WORKS FINE

          EJob job = new EJob { LastName = "Janssen" };

          clientProxy.ProcessJob(job);
      }
  }
  ```

But again: typically, your service methods should be **returning** something that the client can then operate on - after all, you typically don't want to do a `Console.WriteLine` on the server - you want to compute something, look up something etc. and return a response to the **client** which then in turns can e.g. output the result to the console or something....

Comment: Thanks for the response Marc but I am not sure I am entirely with you here.  The entire code as I posted it works perfectly (apart from my mistake having defined the EJob in two namespaces!!)  Therefore I can call a service method without getting a return value and more importantly I CAN also simply serialize the EJob and it is passed on with no problems!

Comment: @Marcel: true - but you basically have it backwards - what you show as "client" is really the **server** and vice-versa. Also: I would highly recommend **NOT** to have a single class that implements the service contract and provides the hosting - those are **separate** responsibilities and should be handled by separate classes

Comment: ok fair enough - I am seeing it from a server mechanism that is going to instruct a variety of clients hence the naming but I see your point!